# Form field custom backend

Tags: grid, forms, grid-serlization

is there a way to create a custom back-end when adding a new field to a form's fieldset?

ie:

```
$newField = $fieldset->addField('new_field', 'text', array(
   'name' => 'foo',
   'value' => 'bar',
   'backend' => 'mymodule/custom_field_type',
   ...
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$fieldset->addType('your_new_type_name', 'Vendor_Extension_Block_Renderer_Classname');
```

Where class 'Vendor_Extension_Block_Renderer_Classname' must extends 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract' class